# Can I draw a processingJS rectangle outside the display window?

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing.js

I am trying to draw a “world” with boundaries using processingJS to draw on a canvas. I want the main screen to be black, with gray around the borders. First I tried:

```
processing.background(175,175,175);
processing.fill(0,0,0);
rect(-4000, -4000, 8000, 8000);
```

Everything else inside of my processingJS code runs fine except for this. I also tried:

```
processing.fill(175,175,175);
processing.rect(-4020, -4020, 8040, 8040);
processing.fill(0,0,0);
rect(-4000, -4000, 8000, 8000);
```

This didn’t work either. Is it even possible to draw a rectangle outside the immediate display area of the canvas?
Thank you so much!

Comment: If it's a `canvas` element, give it a border with css: `#da_canvas { border: 1px solid gray; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't draw outside the canvas.

You would have to create a larger canvas and draw to that.

But if you just want to draw a border, then you can just use CSS or the [p5.dom](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.dom) library.

Comment: thank you so much again! I realized that I was trying to draw the border using absolute coordinates, rather than (correctly) relative to the character.